# Interpreting TG_TABLE_NAME as a value to update row in other table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I want to update a row in the `master_table_info` table with the latest timestamp whenever certain other tables are updated. Each row in the table corresponds to another table. I've created this function, but I cannot get `TG_TABLE_NAME` to be interpreted as a variable value and not a new column. I thus get the error `column some_table does not exist`. How do I interpret it as a value?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION master_table_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('
    UPDATE master_table_info
    SET updated_at = NOW()
    WHERE table_name = %I', TG_TABLE_NAME);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER master_table_timestamp
BEFORE UPDATE ON some_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE master_table_timestamp();
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on the answer/comments so far and reading up the trigger documentation, I realized that I should use `TG_TABLE_NAME` and change to an `AFTER` trigger. However, modifying the table with the trigger produces no changes on `master_table_info`. What could be wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION master_table_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE master_table_info
    SET updated_at = NOW()
    WHERE table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;
    RETURN new;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER master_table_timestamp
AFTER UPDATE ON some_table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE master_table_timestamp();
```

**2nd Edit**

This code in my edit above (based on assistance from the answers) is correct. I just needed to force a manual refresh of the table for it to correctly show.

Comment: %I is a wildcard for a identifier, you must use %L in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%I` replaces the placeholder as an identifier. So the generated SQL would be

```
UPDATE master_table_info
SET updated_at = NOW()
WHERE table_name = some_table;
```

To replace a literal value you would need `%L` as a placeholder in the String. The `%L` placeholder takes care of properly quoting values, so if you use that, the generated string would be:

```
UPDATE master_table_info
SET updated_at = NOW()
WHERE table_name = 'some_table';
```

which is what you expected.

---

However there is no need for dynamic SQL to begin with. As you use that function in a `before` trigger it is important that you return a non-null value from it, otherwise the UPDATE statement would be cancelled.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION master_table_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE master_table_info
      SET updated_at = NOW()
    WHERE table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME;

    RETURN new; --<< return a NON-NULL value here!
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```